# Cancel with confirm message requires double click

Tags: controller, commandbutton

I have a simple example of a custom controller and a VF page.  I have a cancel button on the VF page that shows a confirmation message to save unsaved data before leaving the page.  When I click on the cancel button once, it puts the focus in the select account field, then if I click it again, it shows the confirm message.  I only want to click on it once.  Can someone help with this issue?

```
<apex:page controller="Lesson8Controller">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/>

<apex:sectionHeader title="Lesson 8 Related Lists Conditionally Rendered" subtitle="Lesson 8"/>
<apex:outputText value="Select an account:  " />
<apex:inputField value="{!initialOpp.accountId}" >
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!buildOpps}"/> 
</apex:inputField>
<br/>
<br/>
<apex:outputText value="Student Type:  " />
<apex:selectList value="{!studentType}" size="1" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!studentTypes}" />
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="oppDisplay" action="{!clearSelects}"/>
</apex:selectList>

<apex:pageBlock id="block" >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" 
                  onclick="return confirm('Unsaved Opportunities will be lost.  Are you sure you want to cancel?');"
                  immediate="true" rendered="{!AND(opps.size > 0, unsavedChanges)}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" 
            rendered="{!OR(opps.size = 0, unsavedChanges = false)}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rendered="{!opps.size > 0}" />
    </apex:pageblockbuttons>

    <apex:pageBlockSection id="oppDisplay" title="Select Opportunities to Modify" columns="1" rendered="{!opps.size > 0}" >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opps}" var="op" >
            <apex:column headerValue="Select" >
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!op.selectOpp}" >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changeStudentType}" rerender="oppDisplay" />
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                <apex:outputField value="{!op.oppty.name}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Student Type">
                <apex:outputField value="{!op.oppty.Student_Ambassador__c}" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public class Lesson8Controller {

    /* Variables */

    public Opportunity initialOpp { get; set; }
    public List<OppWithSelect> opps { get; set; }
    public String studentType { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> studentTypes { get; set; }
    public Boolean unsavedChanges { get; private set; }

    /* Constructor */

    public Lesson8Controller() {
        initialOpp = new Opportunity();
        opps = new List<OppWithSelect>();
        studentTypes = csvToSelectOption(Label.Lesson8CustomLabel);
        unsavedChanges = false;
    }

    /* Instance Methods */

    public void buildOpps() {
        for (Opportunity opp : [select name, student_ambassador__c from Opportunity where accountId = :initialOpp.accountId]) {
            opps.add(new OppWithSelect(opp));
        }
        if (opps.isEmpty()) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.Info, 'No Opportunities with this account.'));
        }
    }

    public PageReference cancel() {
        // return to account
        PageReference nextPage;
        if (initialOpp.accountId != null) {
            nextPage = new PageReference('/' + initialOpp.accountId);
            nextPage.setRedirect(true);
        } else {
            nextpage = new PageReference('/');
        }
        return nextPage;
    }

    public void changeStudentType() {
        for (OppWithSelect op : opps) {
            if (op.selectOpp) {
                op.oppty.student_ambassador__c = studentType;
            }
        }
        unsavedChanges = true;
    }

    public void clearSelects() {
        for (OppWithSelect op : opps) {
            op.selectOpp = false;
        }
        unsavedChanges = true;
    }

    public void save() {
        List<Opportunity> updateOppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        for (OppWithSelect op : opps) {
            if (op.selectOpp) {
                updateOppList.add(op.oppty);
            }
        }
        update updateOppList;
        unsavedChanges = false;
    }

    /* Static Methods */

    private static List<String> csvToList(String input) {
        List<String> output = new List<String>();
        if(input != null) {
            for(String value : input.split(',')) {
                if(String.isNotBlank(value.trim())) {
                    output.add(value.trim());
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    private static List<SelectOption> csvToSelectOption(String input) {
        return listToSelectOption(csvToList(input));
    }

    private static List<SelectOption> listToSelectOption(List<String> input) {
        List<SelectOption> output = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(input != null) {
            for(String value : input) {
                output.add(new SelectOption(value, value));
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    /* Inner Classes */

    public class OppWithSelect {
        public Boolean selectOpp { get; set; }
        public Opportunity oppty { get; set; }

        public OppWithSelect(Opportunity newOpp) {
            selectOpp = false;
            oppty = newOpp;
        }
    }
}
```